# Can ZFC decide more values of the Busy Beaver function than PA?

Tags: logic, set-theory, computability, proof-theory, peano-axioms

This is related to a previous question. In that question, I asked whether ZFC can define the Busy Beaver function. I was told even Peano Arithmetic(PA) can define it, and also that PA can't decide that many values of $BB$. Then, can ZFC decide strictly more values of $BB$? I know ZFC can't decide $BB(7918)$.

Comment: This is going to be sensitive to the particular model of computation used (as is the special fact about $7918$ for that matter). Certainly ZFC resolves more halting questions than PA, but that doesn't translate directly into deciding more values of the Busy Beaver function. I'm sure that ZFC does decide more values of BB for any "reasonable" model of computation, but I don't see how to prove it in any particular case.